# Which class or method or function am I in?

Tags: python, mode-line, java

When navigating a source file with incremental search, I often find myself jumping into some context that is taller than the window.  This raises the question: "Which class am I in?".  Or, if the previous developer is prone to writing tall methods: "Which class *and method* am I in?"

I currently answer these questions by interrupting my search to start a new regex search in the reverse direction, then cancel this search with `C g`, then do whatever (usually resume the search).  But, this happens to me so often, I feel like I should have a single command to just print the class/method context in the minibuffer.  Or, even better, if that context was *always* visible.  (I would give up a line of window for that.)

Is there some Emacs gadget that already scratches this itch?  Or, am I just going about this in completely the wrong way?  If it matters, I happen to be working in Python and Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`which-function-mode` displays the current method name.

The following configuration, which I got from [Emacs Redux](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/04/05/which-function-mode/), displays the current method / function / orgmode heading in the top header line rather than the mode line:

```
;; Show the current function name in the header line
(which-function-mode)
(setq-default header-line-format
              '((which-func-mode ("" which-func-format " "))))
(setq mode-line-misc-info
            ;; We remove Which Function Mode from the mode line, because it's mostly
            ;; invisible here anyway.
            (assq-delete-all 'which-func-mode mode-line-misc-info))
```

Do check the linked article for a complete explanation of `which-function-mode`.

Comment: Thank you.  I enabled `which-function-mode`, but I am not seeing anything in either Python or Java.  However, I do see something for C++.  (Perhaps my Emacs is too old.)

Comment: `which-function-mode` does not work in Jython mode.  But, getting out of Jython mode and into Python mode is not so straightforward.